# How to modify an multi object model marked as an asset?

Tags: parent, linked-data, asset-browser

I want to find a workflow to modify multi object models linked in external .blend files via asset browser and make library override.

Requirements:

1. If I change the model in the original file all changes in the external files are automatically taken over (important).
2. The snap mode works in external files (important).
3. If possible not activating modifiers.

Tried:

1. Parent/Childrens not works, childerns are not taken over in the asset library.
2. Collection instances works, except snap mode (uses the origin)

Current workflow:

1. Copy single objects and apply modifiers
2. Merge all single objects via Ctrl-J to one object
3. Mark as asset
4. Link in external .blend file and make library override.

The disadvantage is, I'm not able to make changes in the original file without relinking in external files and apply again all animations, transformations,...

Thanks...